# How can I connect my Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra with my Divoom Timebox Mini?

Tags: bluetooth-pairing, samsung-galaxy-s-23

How can I connect my Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra with my [Divoom Timebox Mini](https://www.divoom-gz.com/product/timebox-mini.html)?

I turned on both of them, and tried to pair the Bluetooth from the S23 but that doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: Sounds to me more like a topic for the Divoom support....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that another device was paired via Bluetooth with the Divoom Timebox Mini: disconnecting that other device allowed the Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra to successfully pair with the Divoom Timebox Mini.